# Audio playing at a lower pitch than original file with clicking noise

Tags: audio, lightworks

I've imported an audio file into Lightworks.  The same problems happen whether the input file is in MP3 or WAV format.  Both original media files play correctly in `mplayer`.

The audio in the file plays slightly lower than it should.  The first tone in the tune is E5; in LightWorks the tone emitted is between D5 and D#5.  This is a frequency ratio of between 1:1.0595 and 1:1.225.  The audio also runs slightly longer, but only by about a second for the entire 6m10s file.  This is a significantly smaller ratio of 1:1.0027.

While the audio is playing, there are frequent and regular mid-pitched clicking sounds audible, at a rate of roughly 10-20 per second.  They are louder when the audio is louder.  These clicking sounds are also audible during playback of video files which have associated audio track; again, the sounds are not audible during playback of the same file under `mplayer`.

I'm running LightWorks on a non-Retina MacBook Pro (2012).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Restarted LightWorks and both problems seem to have disappeared.